# How to read properties file with nested variables with Properties Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have a properties file where I set different DB users. According to the JVM params (or none) I want to connect using one user or the other.

```
env=default
default.user=admin
env1.user=user01
env2.user=user02
jdbc.user=${${env}.user}
```

Example: `java -Denv=env1 -jar myapp.jar`

When using Maven and `org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin` it does not recognize the nested variables and my job reads the wrong value (reads: `${${env}.user}`).

How can I do this with this plugin or any other available for Maven?

By the way, that works if I run my application with Spring framework.

Comment: I always use spring boot functionaly with a yaml file with the different values... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

Comment: Much easier if you would create env-specific prop files i.e. `default.properties`, `env1.properties`, etc

Comment: Agreed with @kan: your variable `env` will specify which property file to pick up when defining `build > resources` in your pom.xml

Comment: For what kind of requirement you need to use properties-maven-plugin...? If you have environment specific configurations you should go different ways like https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/ and just package accordingly and don't use profiles for this...

Comment: As I said guys, I am not running a Spring Boot application (with Spring it works fine). The case here is that I use maven to run flyway (to change my DB) and I need to use properties-maven-plugin to read the properties file before flyway runs (to load DB connection details). One file per "job instance" is not a good idea IMO, because I would be using a properties related to the TEST (CI) environment already. What I need is to run a job (different execution instance) with different users. So the idea here is running it with: `mvn -Denv=env1 -P ci flyway:migrate`

Comment: @danieldestro can you please submit an issue for this? We can implement this feature in new version of a plugin if someone need it: https://github.com/Mikhail2048/properties-maven-plugin/issues